# Proof that sample variance is biased in presence of autocorrelation

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

With no correlation we can show sample variance is unbiased:

$$E[s^2] = E\left(\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}(X_i - \bar{X})^2}{n-1}\right) = \sigma^2$$
Proof
$$E\left(\sum^n_{i=1}(X_i - \bar{X})^2\right) = E\left(\sum^n_{i=1}X_i^2 -2\bar{X}\sum^n_{i=1}X_i + n \bar{X}^2 \right ) = E\left(\sum^n_{i=1}X_i^2 -2\bar{X}n\bar{X} + n \bar{X}^2 \right )  = \sum E(X_i^2) - E(n \bar{X}^2)$$
$$=n\sigma^2 + n\mu^2 - \sigma^2 - n\mu^2 = (n-1)\sigma^2$$

However, if there is autocorrelation among $x_i$, which part of this proof is no longer correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\operatorname{E}[\bar X^2] = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \mu^2$$ is no longer true if there is autocorrelation because $$\operatorname{E}[X_i X_j] \ne \operatorname{E}[X_i]\operatorname{E}[X_j]$$ for $i \ne j$ when there is correlation.

Comment: Ah! Can you write out $E[\bar{x}^2]$ in terms of a sum? Is it $E[\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i \frac{1}{n}\sum x_i]$?

Comment: @user2330624 safer to write something like $E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i \frac{1}{n}\sum_j x_j]$

Comment: Makes sense... $\frac{1}{n^2}E[(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n)(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n)] = \frac{1}{n^2}E[x_1x_1] + E[x_1x_2] +  ...$ But why $\operatorname{E}[\bar X^2] = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \mu^2$ if no auto correlation?

Comment: I see.... $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$ So $E[X^2] = \sigma^2 + \mu^2$... And we can use $Var(\frac{1}{n}\Sigma x_i) = ...$ to solve for this..